# Need to move a copy on Google Drive to new folder without leaving copy behind in original folder

Tags: google-drive

When I make a copy of a document in a shared folder and then move the copy to another shared folder, the copy shows up in the new folder but also stays behind in the original folder. When I delete the copy from the original folder, it deletes from the new folder as well. I just want the copy in the new folder. I used to be able to do this without a problem and now suddenly I can't. Any thoughts?

Comment: What steps are you taking to move the document? There used to be a way to add labels to a document (similar to Gmail labels), thus putting the document (not copies) into multiple "folders" at the same time. Then deleting the document should really delete it, not remove it from one of the folders. Down deep, that feature is probably still there for backward compatibility. But if you use the "Move to..." feature in the My Drive web site's menu, or drag it into a folder on the web site, it should really just move it (add one label and remove the other).

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. I have tried using the "Move to" feature as well as dragging it to the new folder. In both cases, it leaves a grayed out copy of the document in the original folder when I move the copy. Once I leave the original folder and then come back, the copy is no longer grayed out and is there as a regular document. When I delete or alter this copy in any way, the same thing will happen to the copy that is in the new folder. I've never had this problem before. I've been copying and moving documents from this folder for 6 months without a problem (until now!)

Comment: In that case this has to be a bug. Please do report it to Google via the gear menu > Help > Send Feedback.

Comment: @Clueless has the problem been resolved? If not, can you update your question with screenshots of your click path? Perhaps using a 'demo' folder and file.

Answer (score -2):

select the file and hit the 'z' key

Comment: Which does what, exactly?

Comment: Hit  `shift-Z` and a window pops-up that allows you to select a destination folder